# SQL: Check if column contains value from another SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, ssms

I wanted to join the below two tables:

**Table 1:**

```
---------
| Brand |
---------
| Honda |
| Dodge |
| Toyota|
---------
```

**Table 2 Survey Table:**

```
------------------------------------------
|Ser|          Comments                  |
------------------------------------------
| 1 | Honda is a reliable brand          |
| 2 | The dodge Challenger is pure muscle|
| 3 | The new Toyota Corolla is a treat  |
```

Now I want to join both these tables and get **Table 3 :**

```
--------------------------------------------------
|Ser|          Comments                  | Brand |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1 | Honda is a reliable brand          | Honda |
| 2 | The dodge Challenger is pure muscle| Dodge |
| 3 | The new Toyota Corolla is a treat  | Toyota|
```

How do I get Table 3?

I am not being able to Compare both the Comments and the brand list to see if the comments contain the brand name and if yes take the Brand Name. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2):

You can try `JOIN` on `like`

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 t1 INNER JOIN Table2 t2 
ON t2.Comments like '%'+t1.Brand  +'%'
```

[Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2c475/2)

Answer (score 1):

Use LIKE:
Where  UPPER(comments) LIKE '%' || brand || '%'